# NGRX Effect withLatestFrom

Tags: angular, ngrx, effect

I have using withLatestFrom to get the store value in state before switchMap.

```
loadApps$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AppActionsTypes.LoadApps),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRoot.getCritera)),
  switchMap(([action, request]) => this.service.getApps(request).pipe(
     map((result) => new actions.LoadAppsSuccess(result))
  ))
```

The request in switchMap([action, request]) is coming out as `Observable<Criteria>` instead of just Criteria object. I was expecting plain object to be emitted from it and not observable.

The `getCriteria` is of type `MemoizedSelector<object, Criteria>`. It is created as

```
export const moduleState = CreateFeatureSelector<State>('apps');
export const appState = createSelector(moduleState, (state) => state.apps);
export const getCriteria = createSelector(appState, (state) => state.criteria);
```

Comment: Maybe subscribe to your service?

Comment: This is an @NGRX/Effect. Not sure I follow your comment of subscribe to service

Comment: without the definition of your selector its hard to tell what could be going on

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The switchMap will sub for you. I would expect the switchMap to at least do a map on the service that then returns an action (an effect has to return a new action). Like:  
 
switchMap(([action, request]) => this.service.getApps(request).map( response => new myAction.success(response) )). At the moment you are just sending back your service response

Comment: `switchMap` will basically map the source stream to another one, not to a sync. value

Comment: @MikeOne Updated the example

Comment: So for clarity - is the problem coming from your withLatestFrom? If you'd console 'request' inside the switchMap - do you get what you expect?

Comment: @MikeOne - I am getting compile issue. The service method in the switchMap expect a plain Criteria object but the request object in [action, request] is coming as Observable<Criteria>

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. This is indeed strange.. Your code looks good now, so does your selector...

Comment: Can you try to not destructure the incoming array so no [action,request] but instead just do (data), then console it and post the console result here?

Comment: I have stringify the console data and it looks like this: "[ {'type': [App] Load Apps }, { searcText: '', page: 1, size: 15 }]". So the data is coming as plain object but only compile issue as when I hover over the request it shows as Observable<>

Comment: @MikeOne: Any idea why it is giving compile error - Observable<Criteria> is not assignable to Criteria ?

Comment: It's difficult to say. Probably somewhere you typed incorrectly maybe?